# How to handle data that has a digit typo in a number

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have to analyze my data. It is data from World Bank. It has data for all 195 countries. Each country has 15 rows with data for 15 years. At some countries there is a problem with mistyping information. There are input errors in the "Population" column. The person who entered the data sometimes made a mistake with a number, and instead of 36435443, he entered 3643544. As a result, in some years, a 10-fold drop is seen.

I will attach a screen to the graph showing [the population growth of Afghanistan for the years 2000 - 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5IPC.png)

I tried to make an algorithm that detects outliers using std, this is code:

```
# Load data into a pandas DataFrame
gdp_data = afg_data.copy()

# Take the natural logarithm of the data
gdp_data['log_gdp'] = np.log(gdp_data['Population'])

# Create a new column for Z-Scores
gdp_data['z_score'] = np.abs(gdp_data['log_gdp'] - gdp_data['log_gdp'].mean()) / gdp_data['log_gdp'].std()

# Identify outliers
outliers = gdp_data[gdp_data['z_score'] > 1]
outliers
```

[And this is result: (red is considered outlier)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ0I1.png)

Comment: It depend on the use. You can discard the data and interpolate it (good if you want to do some statistical regression). Or discard and nothing, or just keep the data. Or you can send a email to the author, they may already get a correction. Or look the primary source and use that. Every data and job is different and so we have different methods

Comment: Note: many tools have automatic detection of outliers. Data validation is always an important step (which you may use before pandas)

Comment: I want to discard data and use interpolation.
@GiacomoCatenazzi  Can you give me some methods to detect outliers there ?